# Weird repeater problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Repeater control in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("someAttribute") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On Page_Load I have the following code:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Request.QueryString["action"]))
    s.OpenConn("SELECT * FROM someTable;");
else
    s.OpenConn("SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id=1;");

if (s.Read())
{
    repeater.DataSource = s.GetRead();
    repeater.DataBind();
}
```

The problem is that when I enter ?action=something, data is not displayed on the page.
But if I remove ?action=something, I get all the data.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Follow it with a breakpoint on the first line and step through it one line at a time inspecting variables. You will see if the flow is unexpected and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already read and skipped first result in your if statement. Remove this:

```
if (s.Read())
```

Comment: This is the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your query

```
 s.OpenConn("SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id=1;");
```

isn't returning anything. OR, your #Eval statement is returning an empty string. Change this to

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("SomeAttribute")%> I found one!
</ItemTemplate>
```

to make sure you get some output if the repeater's .DataSource property is not an empty list. This way, "I found one!" will be displayed even if "SomeAttribute" is empty.

Tips:

1. Never, EVER EVER embed a query directly in a .ASPX.cs. Used stored procedures or (sigh) parameterized queries.
2. Also, don't do any db interaction in a codebehind page. Refactor your data access into a separate class. You *will* thank me later. Google for n-tiered architecture, unit testing, or separation of concerns for more detailed analysis.
3. You don't need to cast .QueryString[] values to a string. They're already strings.
4. Set a breakpoint on

   if (s.Read())

and see what happens when you get there. This will help you find the problem.

Comment: Both sqls are returning records. That is the first thing to check.

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the object referred to by `s` is doing something really odd, the only reason I can think of, is that `someTable` has no rows with `id = 1`. Have you tried executing the second SQL statement directly in Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: s is an instance of the class for connecting to MSSql database.
On that part, everything is ok.
I have tried to execute sql Management Studio and there is a data with id = 1.